# What is the job of a professor?

Tags: professorship, job

Let's say we're talking about a full-time, tenure-track professor at a U.S. college. Officially I read that the primary job expectations are something like:

1. Research and publications
2. Teaching students
3. Service to the university

But I've heard that effectively, retention committees really only look at #1, the number of publications, in determining whether to award promotions or not. And of course this is consistent with many other signals (e.g., Steven Krantz in *How to Teach Mathematics* recalls a chair telling a new hire in the 60's: "Remember: Our job is proving theorems", although that is contrasted with somewhat modified expectations today [sec 6.1]).

The reason I ask this is because many times when I communicate this to non-academics (that research and publication is the priority), the response is skepticism and/or outright disbelief. So I think that having a canonical, well-formulated answer on SE might be helpful.

How can we best express the true balance of job priorities, and expectations for what kind of work is rewarded, on the part of college professors today?

Comment: If it can be of comfort to you, also in some other countries they just look at #1.

Comment: I think it may just be that in many cases, the standards for 2 and 3 are such that practically everybody can meet them with reasonable effort.  But they still have to do it, and the committee will still look to see whether they have done it.

Comment: The reality is that this varies a lot between institutions.   It is important to understand the majority of faculty in the US teach at community colleges, four year institutions and "regional comprehensive" institutions where reasearch expectactions are much lower than at large research universities.    At many of these institutions you can be tenured with no meaningful research output as long as you've done a good job in teaching and service.  At the toher extreme there are institutions where research is bar far the most important aspect of the tenure process.

Comment: It seems like you'd really need two examples: a research-intensive position, and a research-light (if any occurs at all) position, as @BrianBorchers points out. A professor at a research-focused institution sometimes teaches as little as 1 class per semester, with support from others to grade, hold additional office hours, conduct labs/discussion sections, etc, so they only need to spend less than 10 hours a week (or less) on teaching - and some even buy out of half the year. Meanwhile a professor at a teaching college takes on 4+ classes each semester, little/no assistance.

Comment: I agree with Brian B.  Can you edit your question to specify what type of institution you're talking about?  Also, is this just a who's-right disagreement with a friend, or is there more at stake?  I know you don't have to provide background for your question, but a bit of background would help craft an answer that is truly helpful for whatever the need is. // I suggest you formulate this question as a reference-request.  That would be more useful than some answer on SE that receive a lot of votes.

Comment: Disagree with the close votes; the question is **perfectly clear**. Also, _yes_, there are (at least!) two types of professor positions to take into account here: ones that are more research-focused, and ones that are more teaching-focused. Thankfully, It's not "rocket science," though: I would think that any decent answer to this question would take those opposite ends of the spectrum into account. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I agree with @MadJack here. The question was intended in the general sense; if one must distinguish between classes of institutions, then that's something I didn't anticipate and would be interesting to see in an answer. If references could be provided, that would be excellent but not required.

Comment: It's the *universities* job to serve the *professor*, so he can concentrate on science and teaching. Advancing science includes enough bureaucracy (funding!) as is.

Comment: Lousy teachers often make lousy science, because the good students go somewhere else. One reason why hiring committees are often ignorant of teaching. (Present company etc. excluded! ;-))